# Why is the order of my Taxonomy list ignored when viewing the content?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a Drupal 7 local build and one in PreProd.

Using Git to manage the code base so we know they are aligned.

Moving Taxonomy by dragging items works fine on my Local build however the same exercise does not work on PreProd. The order of the Taxonomy list is ignored in PreProd when viewing the content. I have exported the DB from PreProd and imported into Local. This works on Local!

I have cleared cache every time.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Check for any errors in your browser javascript console, e.g chrome inspector console.

Comment: And click "show weights" after the dragging to see if it's assigned correctly too.